JetBrains dotTrace timeline lacks CPU data (shows "Waiting for CPU" all the time)
I'm trying to profile my .NET 9 WPF application using JetBrains dotTrace.
I've done it in the past, and the timeline view always displayed the CPU activity of each thread, which was very convenient for identifying the performance problem.
But recently, I can see no CPU data, just a pink/salmon background in all threads timelines:

Maybe someone here is a dotTrace power user and can help me determine what is wrong?
My only hypothesis was that dotTrace may not support .NET 9 yet, but when I checked, I had the same problem when profiling .NET 8 apps.
